# Http post request I am facing following issue

Tags: ios7

{ URL: "" } { status code: 500, headers {     "Cache-Control" = private;     "Content-Length" = 3424;     "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=utf-8";     Date = "Fri, 05 May 2017 08:40:26 GMT";     Server = "Microsoft-IIS/10.0";     "X-AspNet-Version" = "4.0.30319";     "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET"; } }

if any know knows help me.

Comment: What is the error. What do you want? btw: there is no url in the request

Comment: AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript", @"text/html", nil];

    [manager POST:@"http://54.169.8.197/V1.0/" parameters:stud progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];

Comment: @Mazz if  you have any idea please help me